# Count number of matching words from an array of words with another array of sentence in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var word_array = ['apple', 'mango', 'school'];

var sentences = [
{name: 'Jon', info: 'Jon takes apple in school'},
{name: 'Anna', info: 'Anna loves to eat mango'},
{name: 'Dani', info: 'Dani wants to go to park today'} 
];
```

I want to count the matched words for each names of the sentences.

```
Output:
Result = [
{name: 'Jon', count: 2},
{name: 'Anna', count: 1},
{name: 'Dani', count: 0}
];
```

Comment: yes. But I couldn't get the expected output.

Comment: So, if you tried, you should post your code including what issue you had. Please, take the stackOverflow [tour] and read [ask], to avoid question close and downvotes, as happened with this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `.map()` and `.reduce()` combination.

As the following:

```js
const word_array = ['apple', 'mango', 'school'];

const sentences = [
  {name: 'Jon', info: 'Jon takes apple in school'},
  {name: 'Anna', info: 'Anna loves to eat mango'},
  {name: 'Dani', info: 'Dani wants to go to park today'} 
];

const result = sentences.map(({name,info}) => {
  const count = word_array.reduce((a,c) => a + info.split(c).length - 1, 0);
  return { name, count };
});

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I found a problem in that. If I modify word_array = ['apple', 'mango', 'school', 'on'] like this. It shows count = 3 for info of 1st sentence. In first sentence, there is a word 'in' not 'on'. I can't figure out why this happens. Can you please help?